# Issue using extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack-3, extracttextwebpackplugin

I am trying to use the Extract Text Webpack Plugin, but I have not been able to generate a new css file for the compiled sass files.

webpack.config.js

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    entry   :   './src/app.js',
    output  :   {
        filename    :   './dist/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader','sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename : 'app.bundle.css'
    }),
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

app.js:

```
var css = require('../css/app.scss');

console.log("This is a test Hi from webpack !!!");
```

Comment: your configuration look good only,did you create the scss files  in css folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I able to generate a new css file for the compiled sass files
- please go through repo for your reference [working example](https://github.com/kasiriveni/stackoverflow-ans/tree/master/48805641)

your configuration looks good only ,my be you miss the path or forgot load css file in index.html or  may be you did not create any scss files

[live example](http://webpack-extract-text-webpack-plugin.surge.sh)

Comment: @Sachindra if you need any help feel free to ask